# Enviar datos a API con Autorizacion bearer por PHP y Curl

Tags: php, api, post, curl

les explico el problema que presento.

Soy muy nuevo en esto de PHP y cURL, sin embargo quiero conectar un formulario que tengo con una API de un servicio para enviar SMS, no logro hacer que funcione y ya no se que más hacer.

Les pongo el código PHP

```php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    extract($_REQUEST);

    switch($cmd){
        case "send":
            $mensaje = $text;
            $mensaje = str_replace(" ", "%20", $mensaje);
            $num = $dest;
            $pais = $c;
            $numero = "52".$num;
            $headers = array(
              'Authorization: Bearer 4|TOKEN',
              'Accept: application/json'
            );

            $data = array(
              'recipient' => $numero,
              'sender_id' => 'HVA',
              'type' => 'plain',
              'message' => $mensaje
            );

            curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
              CURLOPT_URL => "https://app.mas-mensajes.com/api/v3/sms/send",
              CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
              CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
              CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data
            ));

            $respuesta=curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
            $respuesta=json_decode($respuesta);
            echo $respuesta->message;
            break;
        case "credits":
            //Obtain balance from API with CURL
            $headers = array(
                'Authorization: Bearer 4|TOKEN',
                'Accept: application/json'
            );
            curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
                CURLOPT_URL => "https://app.mas-mensajes.com/api/v3/balance",
                CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
                CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers,
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE
            ));
            $respuesta=curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
            $respuesta=json_decode($respuesta);
            echo $respuesta->message;
            break;
    }
}
```

Y el formulario es este:

```html
<form class="col s12 m12" id="apiform" method="post" action="/classes/sms.php">
  <div class="input-field col s4 m4">
    <i class="material-icons prefix ">phone</i>
    <select id="country">
      <option value="52" data-icon="assets/img/mexico.svg" selected>52</option>
    </select>
  </div>
  <div class="input-field col s8 m8">
    <input id="destination" type="tel" class="validate" name="destination" />
    <label for="destination">Destinatario</label>
  </div>

  <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
    <i class="material-icons prefix">sms</i>
    <textarea id="textarea1" class="materialize-textarea" data-length="160" name="content"></textarea>
    <label for="textarea1">Texto del Mensaje</label>
  </div>
</form>

<div class="col s6 m6 center">
  <button class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue darken-1" type="submit" name="action" form="apiform">
    Enviar
    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
  </button>
</div>
```

Ya intente hacerlo de 0 totalmente con un formulario más sencillo y no logro que funcione, espero alguno me pueda ayudar a orientarme sobre que estoy haciendo mal.

El error que me da actualmente es 500 supongo que algo del código esta mal que ni si quiera se ejecuta pero no puedo ver por donde esta el problema.

Como info adicional esta es la consulta de ejemplo que ponen en la documentación de la API

```
    curl -X POST https://app.mas-mensajes.com/api/v3/sms/send \
    -H 'Authorization: Bearer 7|TOKEN' \
    -d "recipient=31612345678" \
    -d "sender_id=YourName" \
    -d "type=plain" \
    -d "message=This is a test message"
```

Comment: Tu código PHP, así como lo presentas, debería dar error. Falta cerrar el `switch`. La varible `$data` esta definida despues de ser utilizada. El arreglo `$headers` esta definido dentro de otro arreglo. Por favor, asegurate de corregir primero todos estos errores de sintaxis.

Comment: @Marcos Tal como comente soy nuevo en esto de PHP y si da error, gracias por la orientación investigare como hacer todo lo que mencionas

Comment: @Marcos he realizado algunos ajustes, no se si eso ya cumple con la sintaxis, o quizá realice algo mal porque aún da error.

Comment: Quita el punto y coma final de esta linea y prueba de nuevo: `CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $data;`, y aplica el cambio que te dí en mi respuesta, no tienen ningun sentido los asteriscos alli, ni la barra final.

Comment: @ArmandoVázquez, ahora tenes 3 errores, el primero es el que te comento `@masterguru`, el segundo estas pasando mal los encabezados  `CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => $headers` y el tercero estas leyendo mal la respuesta `echo $respuesta->message;`

Comment: @Marcos he realizado los cambios que me mencionaron, he actualizado el código para que vean como quedó finalmente. Aunque ahora al menos ya recibo una respuesta el error que me dice es "The given data was invalid." Cuando trato de enviar, y cuando trato de ver el balance no muestra nada "credits"

Comment: @masterguru Una disculpa lo hice desde el Movil

Comment: No, el archivo html está en la raíz del directorio, el archivo php está dentro de /classes/sms.php, el archivo html está tal cual no lo toque de otra API de envíos de sms de otro proveedor, los asteriscos ya venían, y ese archivo funciona bien, sin embargo ya los quite y bueno el error es el mencionado.

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/134324/discussion-between-armando-vazquez-and-masterguru).

Comment: @ArmandoVázquez, en caso de éxito la API de balance devuelve un JSON similar a este `{"status":"success","message":null,"data":{"remaining_unit":"978","expired_on":"18 Feb 2522, 2:50 PM"}}`. **IMPORTANTE** por lo que mas quieras, un publiques un token real. Saludos!

Comment: El token es de pruebas supuestamente ya lo reemplace de cualquier forma por seguridad

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Después de mucho trastear he logrado dar con la solución y el código final es este:

sms.php

```
<?php
if(!empty($_POST)){
    extract($_REQUEST);

    switch($cmd){
        case "send":
            $mensaje = $text;
            $mensaje = str_replace(" ", "%20", $mensaje);
            $num = $dest;
            $pais = $c;
            $numero = $pais.$num;

            curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
              CURLOPT_URL => "https://app.mas-mensajes.com/api/v3/sms/send?recipient=".$numero."&sender_id=SMS&type=plain&message=".$mensaje,
              CURLOPT_POST => TRUE,
  CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer 6|TOKEN'
  ),
              CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
              CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
              CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 0,
              CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION => true,
              CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
            ));

            $respuesta=curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
            $respuesta=json_decode($respuesta);
            echo $respuesta->message;
            break;
        case "credits":
      curl_setopt_array($ch = curl_init(), array(
        CURLOPT_URL =>
        "https://app.mas-mensajes.com/api/v3/balance",
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => TRUE,
         CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
    'Authorization: Bearer 6|TOKEN'
  ),
         
        ) 
      );
      $respuesta=curl_exec($ch); curl_close($ch);
      $respuesta=json_decode($respuesta);
    
      if($respuesta->status == "success"){
        echo json_encode(array(5, $respuesta->data->remaining_unit));
      }else{
        echo json_encode(array(1, $respuesta->message));
      }
    break;
  }
}
```

form.html

```
<form
                  class="col s12 m12"
                  id="apiform"
                  method="post"
                  action="/*classes/sms.php*/"
                >
                  <div class="input-field col s4 m4">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix ">phone</i>
                    <select id="country">
                      <option
                        value="52"
                        data-icon="assets/img/mexico.svg"
                        selected
                        >52</option
                      >
                    </select>
                  </div>
                  <div class="input-field col s8 m8">
                    <input id="destination" type="tel" /*class="validate"*/
                    name="destination" />
                    <label for="destination">Destinatario</label>
                    <!--<span
                      class="helper-text"
                      data-error="wrong"
                      data-success="right"
                      >Helper text</span
                    >-->
                  </div>

                  <div class="input-field col s12 m12">
                    <i class="material-icons prefix">sms</i>
                    <textarea
                      id="textarea1"
                      class="materialize-textarea"
                      data-length="160"
                      name="content"
                    ></textarea>
                    <label for="textarea1">Texto del Mensaje</label>
                  </div>
                </form>

                <div class="col s6 m6 center">
                  <button
                    class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue darken-1"
                    type="submit"
                    name="action"
                    form="apiform"
                  >
                    Enviar
                    <i class="material-icons right">send</i>
                  </button>
                </div>
                <div class="col s6 m6 center">
                  <button
                    id="request_credits"
                    class="btn waves-effect waves-light blue darken-1"
                    type="submit"
                    name="action"
                  >
                    Credito
                    <i class="material-icons right">attach_money</i>
                  </button>
```

Comment: Me alegro que lo hayas conseguido :-)  He quitado todo lo que habia puesto para quitar ruido a la pregunta. Saludos!

Comment: @masterguru gracias por tu apoyo, te quería dar los +50 pero ya no está tu respuesta para hacerlo

Comment: Da igual, tampoco me los merezco, veo que en tu código el form.html sigue con los errores que habia marcado en mis comentarios y mi respuesta, por lo tanto tampoco te ha servido de mucho.  La solución no estaba en mi respuesta, la has encontrado en otra parte, pues lo de los parametros nuevos del CURL era imprevisible y no aparecia en su ejemplo de linea de comandos. Pero gracias, claro :-)

Comment: @masterguru pero fuiste quien más me ayudó por un buen rato solo por eso ya te los mereces, y el código en parte salió de postman volví a darle una checada y funcionó bien entonces ví el snippet que creaba y me base en ese, igual dió problemas pero al final pude solucionarlos. Lo de html yo tampoco lo entiendo pero si le quitó los * no funciona entonces quien sabe jajaja

Comment: je, bueno, pero es que el formulario que pones en tu respuesta para mi esta mal, no liga con los valores del PHP... a ver si se explicarme... usas extract() en el PHP, que teoricamente devuelve en forma de variables los REQUEST recibidos, y en tu form se llaman "destination", "content" y "action", en cambio en el PHP los usas como "$dest", "$text" y $cmd... y dices que te funciona bien... pues yo no entiendo nada, a menos que los mandes con GET y no lo sepa o haya algo en medio que no has dicho.. por eso no puedo aceptar los puntos, si no esta bien desde mi punto de vista no puedo :-)